# Why doesn't "load" or "DOMContentLoaded" stop a prompt from firing before a page is loaded?

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

**Problem**: Javascript fired before my page loaded

**Solution**: Wrapped Javascript in a function and called it after the page loaded.

Unfortunately it didn't work.  Here is my example.

I have a simple 2 page test site.  The first page has a blue background and a link to the second page. When I click the link on the first page the prompt from the script on the second page appears over the first page before the second page has loaded.  `load` or `DOMContentLoaded` don't appear to change this.  I'm sure I'm doing something wrong but I can't spot it.

**page 1**

```
<body style="background-color:blue">
    <a href="page_2.htm">Click this link.</a>
</body>
```

**page 2**

```
<script>
    function globalFunction() {
        prompt("input a number");
    }
</script>
```

I added this code above the function on the 2nd page but the prompt continued to pop up early above the first page before the 2nd page loaded.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", globalFunction);
```

Then I tried this but got the same result.

```
window.addEventListener("load", globalFunction);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is typical behavior when the browser creates a UI element that is not part of the document itself. The browser is a multi-threaded piece of software and a call for a `prompt()` or an `alert()` is handled in a different thread than the JavaScript code is running in. The browser is able to update the UI (in this case with a modal dialog that blocks the JS runtime from continuting) before the browser is able to display the second page.

A solution is to make sure the script doesn't even get initiated until the second page has loaded and defer the prompt just enough so that the browser can update the page display to show it.

In your second file, change the code to:

```
<script>
    window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
      setTimeout(function globalFunction() {
                 prompt("input a number");
      }, 20);
    });
</script>
```

This will defer the function from running for 20 milliseconds, which should be enough time to see the second page.

Comment: This may help, but I'm not sure I understand why it's necessary. Of course  we don't know much about this "second page" and its contents. But if the function is waiting for the "ready" event, it seems weird that *no* content would be there, or  that the window wouldn't have been cleared in preparation for rendering the new content. To have the prompt from the new page show up *over* content from the linked-from page seems pretty bizarre to me, and I'm sure some would see it as a security concern.

Comment: This will help. Making JavaScript a DOM element, starts it from Drawing object but it's interrupted by your prompt.